# Difference between SET with EX option and SETEX in Redis?

Tags: redis

While browsing Redis [command reference](https://redis.io/commands), I came across two very similar comands:

- `SET` with `EX` option: https://redis.io/commands/set
- `SETEX`: https://redis.io/commands/setex

The `SETEX` boasts itself as an atomic way to do `SET` and `EXPIRE`, yet by the looks of it the same thing can be achieved with `SET EX` as it's also a single command.

SETEX was added in `2.0.0`, while `EX` parameter was added in `2.6.12`, so it seems that the former remains for the backwards compatibility, but for some reason it's not marked as deprecated.

Did I miss anything? Are there any valid cases for using `SETEX` nowadays?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`SET` documentation](https://redis.io/commands/set#options) says:

> Note: Since the SET command options can replace SETNX, SETEX, PSETEX, it is possible that in future versions of Redis these three commands will be deprecated and finally removed.

So it's safe to say that there's no reason to use `SETEX` if you have Redis version 2.6.12 or higher.